# Sqlalchemy results as dictionary with specified column as key

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

Looking to conveniently select some data into a dictionary keyed by specified columns, like so:

```
# pseudocode
results = session.query(MyModel).all(index_result_by=MyModel.id)
print(results.__class__)
<class 'dict'>
print(results[5])
<MyModel 5>
```

I could use a loop or dict comprehension, but is there anything built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select tuples of `id, instance` and pass to `dict()`:

```
results = dict(session.query(MyModel.id, MyModel).all())
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Way cool, I didn't know you could combine columns and full objects like that.